# How to update datagridview combobox datasource on button_click?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have product addition form.
1. This form contains Textboxes, 2 Comboboxes, Lables, Buttons and a DATAGRID.

2. Datagrid contains 4 textboxes and 2 comboboxes.
3. The 2 Comboboxes in datagrid are bounded to a datasource1 source.
4. Also the Combobox Outsite datagrid are also databound to the datasource1 as the combobox in datagrid.
5. I use a button to show a form to add values to the datasource1.
6. I use a Refresh Button to reload values on combobox which is outside datagrid.

My Concern here is only that

When Refresh Button is clicked i also want to reload combobox values in datagrid.
But the values in datagrid the already entered should not be reloaded.

Note: All the combobox and datagrid are bounded during design time.

Following Are the steps.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

The method that i am using on button Refresh is as follows.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadLabel();    /* load combobox5 with Label*/
        loadShade();    /* load combobox1 with Shade*/
        dataGridView1.Update();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: where are you binging the datagridview..? also if you are going to do it on different button clicks then befpre assigning the dataGridView1.DataSource, set it `= Null` then do the assigning and databinding is this done at design time or runtime 
`Also the Combobox Outsite datagrid are also databound to the datasource1 as the combobox in datagrid.`

Comment: Dear DJ Kraze, I am not binding the datagridview by doing any click button during RUN TIME, but when i designed the form, i bound the datagridview combobox, means i bound it in design time.

Comment: I still think that you would need to rebind that during runtime but there are many ways to skin a cat..